# Is human a fundamental flaw in our political systems?

Tags: politics

I've been thinking on the persistent challenges and flaws within our political systems, and I'm increasingly convinced that the root of many issues isn't the structure or ideology of these systems themselves, but rather the human element within them. It seems that the very act of a system attempting to govern or manage itself is inherently problematic due to human biases, self-interests, and imperfections. Now I question whether any political system managed by humans can ever truly be just, efficient, or serve the common good effectively.

Based on what I've wrote, would you consider these observations about our politics to be an accurate critique?

Comment: Maybe a political system (and society) without humans can be "perfect"... As Stalin said: "No persob, no problem".

Comment: The anarchist might reverse this reasoning: no political system is fit or just for the human being . . . is the coat too big for the man, or the man too small for the coat?

Comment: In nicomavhiean ethics Aristotle writes about how politicians are basically meant to care about our needs, so that might mean that instead of being flaw humans are essential?

Answer (score 1):

"can ever truly be just" - If you try to look at the issue from the Creator's point of view, you will probably realize that the 'just' system with some level of perfection - is not desirable by the Creator. The whole purpose of individual lives as well as the life of society is to grow, advance, change and get better. For that goal, a 'just' and perfect political system would create stagnation and would be counterproductive. Imperfect people create a lot of energy, and this seems to be what the Creator ordered.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I follow you. You say that "being human" is a "fundamental flaw" in our "political systems".

Now if a certain design of a steering wheel in a new model of a car was a fundamental flaw, then of course the designer would have to redesign it.

But we cannot redesign humans despite all the rhetoric of transhumanists. We are what we are. Nor can we take humans out of the equation either. If we did, it would not be a political system but merely an automated bureaucratic mechanism.

This "flaw" as you put it has been noted since Plato wrote *The Republic* and revisited in several of his other political books. He found no solution. It is also why St Augustine wrote, *The City of God* in response. Here, in our finite, mortal world of beginings and endings, nothing is perfect and we can only approximate the ideal perfection that we can only imagine but never bring to fruition. St Augustine put this down to our imperfection and said that only in the city of God would justice rule supreme. It also happens to be a central plank in the underlying philosophy in the Arthurian mythos in its later Christianised phase of the Fisher King.

Answer (score -1):

Abstractly, it is often possible to build a system with a very low failure rate even if the only available components to build it from have a high failure rate, e.g. through use of tools like redundancy and error detection / correction.

In order to argue that "since humans are flawed, any system they build must be flawed to the same extent", you would need to argue that any political system, built out of people as its components, doesn't have tools like these available, or can't effectively deploy them. This could be argued for, but you're not currently presenting that argument.